# Create AWS Cognito programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am searching for the option whether we can create entire AWS Cognito using some CLI commands or using APIs. I don't find any way from my search. 
Please help me to out what can be automated in AWS Cognito.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. AWS Cognito has no concept of instance. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i mean, can i copy entire settings of dev environment aws cognito to other environment?

Comment: AWS CLI doesn't support such functionality, but you can use AWS Cloudformation 
 or Terraform to create a stack and than use for managing multiple environments. (I prefer Terraform)

Comment: does AWS Cloudformation Template same like Azure ARM Template?

Comment: Yes. AWS Cloudformation Template is like Azure ARM Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some of research i am posting answer to my question.

Thank you @yossi for the above comments.

1) AWS Cloudformation Template to create and replicate entire AWS cognito settings
2) AWS cognito provides APIs for most of the CRUD operations
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AddCustomAttributes.html 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/iam-examples-policies.html
3) AWS provides SDKs to integrate APIs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#createUserPoolClient-property